# How to apply every sub-division surface modifier in a blender file

Tags: modifiers, shortcut, subdivision-surface

So I have hundreds of subdivision surface modifiers:

[image]

(Theres way more)

And I need to apply them all, but if I did it one by one, it will take hours.
So is there a way to apply all the sub-division surface modifers at once?

I have a bunch of other modifiers that I can't apply though (Armature, array. etc) because it will ruin my scene. So I need to ONLY apply the sub-division modifers, and no other modifiers.

Thanks
Daniel

Comment: Do they have different levels of subdivision?

Comment: Some of them do

Comment: Hmmm, I was thinking if it would be possible to join all the pieces together then apply, but due to the other modifiers and different subdivision levels I'm not sure how well that would work. You could probably do that for some of the pieces though at least. Do you have the modifier tools addon on to make applying easier at least?

Comment: This sounds easy to do with scripting

Comment: Hint : Instead of `m.type == 'ARMATURE'` use `m.type == 'SUBSURF'`